# Open and close process in Laravel

Tags: laravel, proc-open

In web.php I start the process in this route

```
Route::get('/startProcess',function(){
   $descriptorspec=.......
   $process1 = proc_open('php C:\Process1.php',$descriptorspec,$pipes);

   // Here I need to save a reference to the process - $process1
});
```

I need to close this process in another route

```
Route::get('/stopProcess',function(){

   // Here I need to get a reference to the process - $process1

   proc_close( $process1 )
});
```

Where do I save a reference to the process and how do I get it ?

Answer (score 1):

`proc_open` returns a resource, and resources can't be serialised so I don't think you can retrieve the resource again after the request ends.

Here is a potential solution:

```
Route::get('/startProcess',function(){
   $descriptorspec=.......
   $process1 = proc_open('php C:\Process1.php',$descriptorspec,$pipes);
   $status = proc_get_status ($process1);
   return response()->json([
      'pid' => $status['pid'];
   ]);
});
```

Then you can use the PID retrieved to kill the process using a shell operation:

```
Route::get('/stopProcess/{pid}',function($pid){
     shell_exec("kill -9 $pid");
});
```

You can call the later as `https://example.com/stopProcess/12345`

Comment: shell_exec is not working even if I call it in the next line after proc_open and proc_get_status

Comment: Is this in Linux?

Comment: this is in Windows 10

Comment: on windows 10 you can try `shell_exec("taskkill /F /PID $pid");`

Comment: shell_exec("kill -9 $pid"); also works. It should be preceded by the following lines $ descriptors = array (0 = > array ("pipe", "r"), 1 = > array ("pipe"," w"), 2= > array ("pipe"," w"); fclose( $ pipes [0])... fclose($pipes[2])  Thanks !

Comment: But in general, the problem is not solved. When closing, I need fclose( $ pipes [0])... fclose($pipes[2]). But these are also resources. And I can't pass them in the request

Comment: The open pipes would get closes when the request ends, but that means they would not be available in the next request at all if you need to do something with them. Overall this is not an ideal